# Getting location when button is clicked

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I am trying to get the app to send a web service call using the GPS coordinates when the user clicks on a button.

When I click on a button, it creates a `locationManager` and `requestLocationUpdates` and sends the web service with the GPS coordinates retrieved from the `LocationManager` and then `removelistener` in the `AsyncTask`.

The problem is that when I click the button it's not able to get the location every time as the `LocationManager` is not able to get the GPS coordinates instantly, but only in the `onLocationChanged` callback. How can I wait for this callback without blocking the UI?

I have tried to use `Looper` within the `AsyncTask` and got it working but it crashes the app when I click on the button for the sixth time.